# How to count the number of columns in a table which are PK (PL-SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**INTRODUCTION**

I came across this exercise which ask me to write a script which counts how many rows there are, count how many columns, with PKs, there are and the storage consumed.

Reading the docs I came across this useful line:

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR TABLE;
```

This line gathers statistics of a given `table_name` which then can be accessed as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'table_name'
```

Here it displays a lot from the table we previously inputted but I can't find the number of columns which have PKs and the storage consumed by such table.

**My TRY AT PL-SQL is:**

```
DECLARE

    v_nom_table VARCHAR2(10);
    v_num_rows NUMBER(100);
    v_num_col_pk NUMBER(100);
    v_num_storage NUMBER(100);

BEGIN

    v_nom_table := &input_nom_table;

    ANALYZE TABLE v_nom_table COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR TABLE;

    SELECT num_row INTO v_num_rows 
    FROM user_tables
    WHERE UPPER(table_name) LIKE UPPER(v_nom_table )

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        'La tabla ' || v_nom_table || ' tiene: ' || v_num_rows || ' filas, ' 
         || v_num_col_pk || ' columnas con PK y ocupa ' || v_num_storage
    );
```

QUESTION

**How do I get the number of columns involved in PK and the storage consumed by the given table?**

Comment: *"How do I get the number of columns involved in PK "* Not sure how much Oracle database confirms to the SQL standards but i think you are looking for the `information_schema` database which should hold the meta data for SQL databases/schemas and tables.  *"and the storage consumed by the given table?"* Most likely you would have to calculate that yourself not sure if Oracle exposes this information somewhere.

Comment: Also which Oracle [version](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2250946?start=0&tstart=0) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical solution to list the columns involved in the primary key of a table is to:

- query Oracle views `USER_CONSTRAINTS` (or `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`) to find the record that relates to the primary key (`CONSTRAINT_TYPE = P`) of thet table
- then lookup the related columns in view `USER_CONS_COLUMNS`

Consider:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_constraints cons
INNER JOIN user_cons_columns cols ON cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND cons.table_name = ?
```

---

When it comes to computing the storage space consumed by a given table, that's a different question. A solution is to use column `BLOCKS` from view `USER_TABLES`. THen all you have to do is multiply this value by the block size of the tablespace in which the table is stored in the `ALL_TABLESPACES` view, in column `BLOCK_SIZE`.